Sprite goes slow with some keys while withh others faster
I'm making a SDL and C++ game engine and I don't know where I'm failing. Here iss my code:
Game.cpp

int mapKeyToInt(SDL_Keycode key) {
    switch (key) {
        case SDLK_w:
        return 1; // Up
        break;
        case SDLK_UP:
            return 1; // Up
        break;
        case SDLK_s:
        return 2; // Down
        break;
        case SDLK_DOWN:
            return 2; // Down
        break;
        case SDLK_a:
        return 3; // Left
        break;
        case SDLK_LEFT:
            return 3; // Left
        break;
        case SDLK_d:
        return 4; // Right
        break;
        case SDLK_RIGHT:
            return 4; // Right
        break;
        default:
            return 0; // Default
        break;
    }
}

void Game::HandleEvents()
{
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    switch (event.type)
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        _closed = true;
        break;
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->xspeed = 5;
        entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->yspeed = 5;
        switch (mapKeyToInt(event.key.keysym.sym)) {
            case 4: // Right
                // Move player to the right
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Walk);
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->moveRight();
                break;
            case 3: // Left
                // Move player to the left
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Walk);
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->moveLeft();
                break;
            case 1: // Up
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Walk);
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->moveUp();
                break;
            case 2: // Down
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Walk);
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->moveDown();
                break;
            case 0: // Default
                // Handle other key inputs if needed
                break;
            case SDLK_k:
                // Trigger attack animation
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Attack);
                break;
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Crouch);
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    
    case SDL_KEYUP:
        switch (mapKeyToInt(event.key.keysym.sym)) {
            case 1: // Up
            case 2: // Down
            case 3: // Left
            case 4: // Right
            case SDLK_k:
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                // Stop player movement if no movement input
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->xspeed = 0;
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->yspeed = 0;
                entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>()->changeAnimationFrames(Idle);
                break;
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                _closed = true;
            default:
                break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

...
  // Method to change the animation frames dynamically
    void changeAnimationFrames(const std::vector<std::string>& frames) {
        _Rframes = frames;

        // Reset frame index and last frame time
        frameIndex = 0;
        lastFrameTime = SDL_GetTicks(); // Reset last frame time to current time

        // Load the new animation frames
        TextureManager m;
        texs = m.LoadAnimation(frames);
    }

    void moveUp() {
        if (transform != nullptr) { // Check if transform is not null
            dest.y -= yspeed;
            transform->position.y = static_cast<int>(dest.y);
        }
        //_flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE;
    }

    void moveDown() {
        if (transform != nullptr) { // Check if transform is not null
            dest.y += yspeed;
            transform->position.y = static_cast<int>(dest.y);
        }
        //_flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE;
    }

    void moveLeft() {
        if (transform != nullptr) { // Check if transform is not null
            dest.x -= xspeed;
            transform->position.x = static_cast<int>(dest.x);
        }
        _flip = SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL;
    }

    void moveRight(){
        if (transform != nullptr) { // Check if transform is not null
            dest.x += xspeed;
            transform->position.x = static_cast<int>(dest.x);
        }
        _flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE;
    }
...

In theory if I press key up, it should go at the same speed as if I pressed W, but the real scenario it's that it goes faster with the key arrows, while WASD goes slower. I've tried several methods and none worked. PLEASE HELP!

maybe something to do with key repeat

You're checking for "key press" events.  This means your movement is tied to the operating system's keyboard repeat speed.  Unless, for some reason, you specifically want this behavior, you should have a main game loop running at a fixed speed, and check for the state of each key (down or up) during each pass through the loop.
